# How to convert (+) into corresponding join in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone tell me how to convert Oracle (+) as joins in snowflakes is there any feasible way to convert.

I have a very complex 1k line SQL script which needs has 30+ (+) operators as joins.

Could anyone please help me

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert Oracle's outer join syntax to ANSI syntax. So it will be compatible with Snowflake and rest of the world (Even Oracle supports ANSI join syntax). You should re-write them manually but it's not a hard work:

Oracle:

```
SELECT d.department_name,
       e.employee_name      
FROM   departments d, employees e
WHERE  d.department_id = e.department_id (+) 
AND    d.department_id >= 30
ORDER BY d.department_name, e.employee_name;
```

ANSI

```
SELECT d.department_name,
       e.employee_name     
FROM   departments d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e ON d.department_id = e.department_id
WHERE  d.department_id >= 30
ORDER BY d.department_name, e.employee_name;
```

You can find explanations on that page (for left/right/outer joins):

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-for-beginners-joins#left-outer-join

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake supports the (+) operator according to the [WHERE clause documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/where.html#joins-in-the-where-clause).